# add t score to existing data set in sas

Tags: merge, sas, statistics, rank, standardized

How do I add a new variable with a score in an existing dataset in SAS?

```
proc standard data=orig out=age_t mean=50 std=10; 
var age ;
run;
```

I want to create a new variable age_t in the original dataset with the t score for every observation

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with your question. Here's an example of adding the average value, you can expand it to your case as needed: https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/add_average_value_to_dataset.sas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Left Join` your original table with the `Proc Standard` output. Full code below:

Creating Dummy Data:

```
data orig;
input name $ age ;
datalines;
jackieChan 50
Tom 70
Lee 45
Tim .
Sarah 29
Rose 33
;
```

Saving Standard output to new table "stnd_age":

```
proc standard data=orig out=stnd_age mean=50 std=10; 
var age ;
run;
```

Left Joining Orig table with stnd_age:

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
select orig.* , stnd_age.age as age_t
from orig left join stnd_age on orig.name=stnd_age.name;
quit;
```

Result:

[image: Left Join]

```
name=Sarah age=29 age_t=39.873841923 
name=Tim age=. age_t=. 
name=Tom age=70 age_t=65.189237115 
name=jackieCh age=50 age_t=52.840263851
```

Comment: You are welcome, the down vote is unfair as you had a genuine and clear question. I will up vote you.